# Why is it preferable to use a host name (domain) rather than an IP address in a URL?

Tags: html, url, dns, ip

I have just started to teach myself how to use Javascript HTML etc.

Why is it preferable to use a host name (domain) rather than an IP address in a URL?

Comment: Which rolls of the tongue better, `did you Google it?` or `did you 216.58.192.14 it?`

Comment: or did you `2a00:1450:4009:80b::200e` it?

Comment: hahaha! ok point taken, thank you! :)

Comment: Also, a single IP/server may host several different domains. For example, in HTTP, the domain is specified in the `Host` header of the request. Without specifying the domain, the server(s) behind the IP would not know what to do with your request.

Comment: As a counterpoint, a hostname requires a DNS lookup.  If you are writing a program that calls the same URL many times, you could lookup the IP address once and then use it to fetch the URL each time.  That would make your program run faster.

Answer (score 1):

If an IP address points to a vhost, there are sometimes occasions where the one server (with one public-facing IP address) is listening for requests on port 80 for several different websites (different host headers), presenting a different website depending on what URL the user typed.

A nice eloquent and more in depth answer is [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/106882/how-do-you-have-one-ip-address-and-many-websites).

Comment: This is the only correct answer that takes into account multiple domains on a single IP/server.

Answer (score 0):

It also gives you a much easier transition path should you need to move your application/website to a different host. i.e., you can build your new website on an entirely different host, test it either by IP address or altering a hosts file, and then, once you're satisfied, simply switch the DNS entry to point to your new host.